# How do I randomly generate number to change contrast of a UIImage?

Tags: ios, xcode, random, uiimage, contrast

I need to randomly generate the contrast of a UIImage. How do i do so? Also if you could tell me how to do the same for hue, brightness, sharpness, saturation, ect.

Answer (score 0):

you can generate a random number this way:

```
int x = arc4random() % 1000;
```

that generates a random number between 0 and 999. a float you 
can generate with:

```
#define ARC4RANDOM_MAX      0x100000000

double myValue = floorf(((double)arc4random() / ARC4RANDOM_MAX) * 10.0f);
```

Comment: You mean between 0 and 999.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this image filtering category

https://github.com/esilverberg/ios-image-filters

and just go:

```
[myImage brightness:arc4random() % 256 / 255]
```

Comment: due to automatic reference counting, many lines in the github project are errors and warnings. Im not totally sure how to get around them...